# Determining a column type modification (TYPMOD) from a PostgreSQL C function

Tags: c, postgresql

I have created a type for example **MYTYPE(*X*)** in Postgres and have created a table like the following:

**create table t0( c0 mytype(80) );**

I then create a function called **MY_ENCRYPT( MYTYPE )**. This function takes the MYTYPE value and does a 3DES encrypts the value. From within the MY_ENCRYPT function is there some way for me to get the value of ***X*** (the typmod) for the column so that I can check to see if the value falls in the proper range (i.e. 80 - overhead)? I need to do this because there are additional overhead during the the encryption which will result in the encrypted data being greater than the actual input value.

**Note:** The MYTYPE cannot be a special specifically for encrypted data it must be a generic type that can be used for other purposes. So, I cannot simply account for the additional overhead in a special type it has to be done in the function or somewhere else not tied specifically to a type.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the type modifier is not stored in the `Datum`. It is passed to the type input function so that it can use it to parse and verify the string representation. So you cannot get it in your function, unless you somehow include it in the internal representation of `mytype`.

The only place in PostgreSQL where the type modifier is persisted is the table column definition.